# Disconnecting android phone

Tags: usb, android

I have a weird problem. I can connect my android phone to my laptop, it keeps connecting/disconnecting (about twice per second). I tried on another laptop with Ubuntu installed, and it worked fine.

Big problem is that, aside of no file transfer, I can't charge my phone. I keep getting  the message "unable to open MTP device  '[usb:003,]'", where num keeps increasing (I assume it is communication attempts).

What may be causing this problem? I have no idea where to start. It's the only USB device that does that (my ipod charges fine, and I can even access the music no problem).

Is there a way I can "deaden" one of the usb ports, such that only power is provided, but no data transfer attempts?

P.S.: My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S2.

P.P.S: It does that on all USB ports.

Comment: Do you have go-mtpfs installed? If yes, have you tried mounting trough this?

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the usb cable which was bad, with a **good quality USB cable** it corrected the problem

And as a workaround, using **Samba on your phone** as mentioned in `[this tread][1]` worked for me as the best solution (take a look @ the sdcard share adding in the settings of the application)

Comment: Bang on, I had the exact same problem. Trying a different cable fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PTP connection instead of MTP - for some reason I always have this problem in Ubuntu<sub>, but never in Fedora...</sub>

You should get a Notification on connection, touch it and select PTP:

[image]

I think on older versions of Android there was 'Mass Storage Mode'

Works on Android 4.1

Also, make sure `libmtp` is installed.

---

<sub>Also note, there is a revolutionary concept - turning the phone *off*...</sub>

Comment: I had tried both PTP & MTP, same behaviour. I had libmtp installed already (under libmtp-common)

Comment: [This](http://blog.jeshurun.ca/technology/connecting-the-google-nexus-7-to-ubuntu-mint-over-usb) could be of help...

Comment: Thanks; I was never able to transfer files from ubuntu to Android. Still, my problem persists: Ubuntu tries to connect to the device, but gives a DBus error *org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)* .

Comment: As I pointed in the OP, I cannot even *charge* my phone (but I can do so on other ubuntu computers). This seem to be an install-specific problem, not a ubuntu-specific problem.